# Comparing two strings in Bash

Tags: bash, scripts, password

I would like to make a script that deletes a directory with `rmdir` after confirming with a password using `read` to set the variable.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
echo "Password:"
read -t 30 S1
    S2='55555'
if [ $S1=$S2 ]; then
    rmdir /home/william/test
else
    echo "fail"
sleep 10
fi
```

So, I have the `-x` to try to debug it but every time the script either fails to echo (if I put the password in wrong) or it wont remove the directory needed.

If someone has a modifiable script that I could use or if you could point out the problems with the current script that would be great.

Answer (score 17):

The right way to compare those two strings (`S1` and `S2`) using `if` is:

```
if [ "$S1" = "$S2" ]
```

Do not be stingy in use spaces in this case.

See: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: TLDP is not an authentic site as it has a lot of inconsistencies and errors.  I would advise that we don't use it as a reference.

Answer (score 6):

In bash scripting you need to compare two variable with below method.

```
if [ "var1" != "var2" ]; then
  Do something
fi;
```

Spaces are important

Answer (score 4):

You may also use GNU `test`, for example:

```
test s1 = s2 && echo Equal || echo Not equal
```

In your context, it is:

```
test "$S1" = "$S2" && rmdir -v /home/william/test
```