# Bash If Statment help

Tags: bash

I have this if statment:

```
if $type = 1 then
 date +%s | md5 | base 64 | head -c $length >> $name.txt
        elseif $type = 2 then
        date +%s | shasum | base 64 | head -c $length >> $name.txt
                elseif $type = 3 then
                openssl rand -base64 $length  >> $name.txt
fi
```

and i keep getting the error:

```
./password: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./password: line 32: `fi'
```

it is probably me doing something silly but i can not work out where i am wrong!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Yes, you are doing something silly: it's `elif`, not `elseif`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - 'if' statement: compare two strings](http://askubuntu.com/questions/351765/bash-if-statement-compare-two-strings)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Always organize your code and use -eq whenever performing conditions with integers

```
if [ $type -eq 1 ]
        then 
     date +%s | md5 | base 64 | head -c $length >> $name.txt 

   elif [ $type -eq 2 ]
       then 
           date +%s | shasum | base 64 | head -c $length >> $name.txt 

   elif [ $type -eq 3 ]
     then 
         openssl rand -base64 $length >> $name.txt 

fi
```

Comment: While the code maybe correct, a good answer should explain why the code in question didn't work and this code does.

Comment: if my answer was helpful choose as answer give a vote .And your welcome